# render query count(DISTINCT "reviews".id) as my_count even if count result is 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, rails-postgresql

In a query below rails counts how many reviews and comments publication have and order results in a DESC order.

For instance:

publication one: 2 reviews + 10 comments = 12(my_count)

publication two: 2 reviews + 5 comments = 7(my_count)

In case above query can find and render publication as expected, however if:

publication three: **0** reviews + 5 comments = 5(my_count)

in this case query will not render publication three, because review value is 0. How could I make it render even if one or both values are 0? So, basically I want render all records in DESC order no matter if value 0.

Thanks for guidance!

```
@publication = Publication.joins(:reviews, :publication_comments)
                          .select('"publications".*, count(DISTINCT "reviews".id) + count(DISTINCT "publication_comments".id) as my_count')
                          .group('"publications".id')
                          .order("my_count DESC")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make left join with reviews and probably publications_comments tables. Please try this:

```
@publication = Publication.includes(:reviews, :publication_comments)
                      .select('"publications".*, count(DISTINCT "reviews".id) + count(DISTINCT "publication_comments".id) as my_count')
                      .group('"publications".id')
                      .order("my_count DESC")
```